# Getting an "Uncaught TypeError" in a React app

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I'm trying to make a "delete button" on my Feedback app for my practice. It should look just like a Feedback app, there's a list of all of my feedback and each feedback has a delete button. I'm successfully showing all of my feedback. Still, I'm currently getting an error around my delete button saying Uncaught TypeError: handleDelete is not a function and I have no idea how to fix it. How can I make it work?

My codes are as follows:
**for App.js**

```js
        import Header from './component/Header';
    import './App.css';
    import { useState } from 'react'
    import FeedbackData from './data/FeedbackData'
    import FeedbackList from './FeedbackList';

    function App() {
     const [feedBack , setFeedback] = useState(FeedbackData)

     const deleteFeedback = (id) => {
      if (window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to delet that?')){
        setFeedback (feedBack.filter((item) => item.id !== id ))
      }
    }
      return (
        <> 
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
        <FeedbackList item ={feedBack} handleDelete ={deleteFeedback}/>
        
        </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

**and for FeedbackList.js**

```js
  import React from "react";
import FeedbackItem from './component/FeedbackItem'

function FeedbackList( feedback , handleDelete ) {

    if (!feedback || feedback.length === 0) {
      return <p>there is no feedback</p>}
    
    return (
      <div className="feedback-list">
  
        {feedback.item.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item ={item}
           handleDelete={handleDelete}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  

export default FeedbackList;
```

**and for FeedbackItem.js**

```js
    

import React from "react";
import Card from "./shared/Card";
import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'
function FeedbackItem( {item , handleDelete} ) {

    return (
      <Card>
        <div className="num-display">{item.rating}</div>
        <button  className="close" onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
            <FaTimes color="purple" />
        </button>
        <div className="text-display">{item.text}</div>
      </Card>
    );
  }
  

export default FeedbackItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

`function FeedbackList( {feedback , handleDelete} ) {}`

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, please try adding more context so everyone knows what are you trying to indicate from your code only answer. See other answers on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Mahla, you may have just forgot braces on FeedbackList.

```
function FeedbackList( feedback , handleDelete ) { //old
function FeedbackList({ feedback , handleDelete }) {  // new, with braces
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Update FeedbackList.js

```
 import React from "react";
import FeedbackItem from './component/FeedbackItem'

function FeedbackList({ feedback , handleDelete} ) {

    if (!feedback || feedback.length === 0) {
      return <p>there is no feedback</p>}
    
    return (
      <div className="feedback-list">
  
        {feedback.item.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item ={item}
           handleDelete={handleDelete}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  

export default FeedbackList;
```

You were not sending props as object.

Answer (score 0):

`FeedbackList`  component receives `item and handleDelete` as props from the parent, so you can destructure it like you did.

```
function FeedbackList({ feedback , handleDelete })
{ ... }
```

Or

```
function FeedbackList(props) { 
const { feedback , handleDelete } = props
// also log and see what other things you get props
console.log(props)
{ ... }
}
```

Or

```
function FeedbackList(props) { 
console.log(props.feedback)
console.log(props.handleDelete())
{ ... }
}
```